# Spring PagingAndSortingRepository returns all results instead of desired page size

Tags: spring, spring-data-jpa

I am using Spring Data JPA and I have a repository which extends PagingAndSortingRepository. My issue is that I have a query in which returns all of the results instead of the desired page size (100). I can't seem to find an issue that is wrong. Can anyone assist please?

```
@Test
public void testFindPageByStartAndEndDate() {
    Timestamp endDate = Timestamp.valueOf("2017-06-14 09:18:42");
    Timestamp startDate = Timestamp.valueOf("2017-05-19 01:31:23");

    PageRequest pageRequest1 = new PageRequest(0, 100, Sort.Direction.ASC, "orderDate");
    Page<Order> page1Orders = orderRepository.findPageByStartAndEndDate(startDate, endDate, pageRequest1);

    assertThat(page1Orders.getTotalElements(), greaterThan(0L));
    //
    //
    // Test Fails Here
    //     Expected: a value less than <101L>
    //          but: <139L> was greater than <101L>
    // 
    //
    assertThat(page1Orders.getTotalElements(), lessThan(101L)); 
}
```

This is the query that I am using.

```
@Query("SELECT o FROM Order o  WHERE o.orderDate >= ?1 AND o.orderDate <= ?2")
Page<Order> findPageByStartAndEndDate(@Param("startDate") Timestamp startDate,
                                      @Param("endDate") Timestamp endDate,
                                      Pageable pageable);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`getTotalElements()` returns the count without pagination.

You get the number of elements present in the slice with `getNumberOfElements()`.

See the implementation of `Page` as a reference [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/domain/PageImpl.html).